# How do i fix the device status on it on Gimp 2.10.18 that says only Core Pointer?

Tags: gimp

I don't know what i did, but there is no information about the tool i am using now. The image is the device status, below the tool box. I am on the warp tool. It only says core pointer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/99BB3.png

Comment: Do you use any special input devices? Tablet styluses will appear there, for example.

Comment: There's nothing wrong here.  "Core Pointer" is what the Device Status will show if you are using a mouse.  Select the Tool Options tab instead if you want to see the tool options.

Comment: thanks for your help!

Comment: @BillyKerr: I hope you don't mind, but I added that as an answer so that yoptra can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: @SeanDuggan - that's absolutely fine. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

As per Billy Kerr's comment, "Core Pointer" is the basic mouse cursor in [Device Status](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-device-status-dialog.html). You will see other input devices if you have something like a tablet and stylus.

> This window gathers together the current options of Toolbox, for each of your input devices: the mouse (named “Core pointer”) or either the tablet, if you have one. These options are represented by icons: foreground and background colors, brush, pattern and gradient. Excepted for colors, clicking on an icon opens the window which lets you select another option; the tool-box will be updated when changing. You can drag and drop items to this dialog.